# How to scroll an item to the top of the list android?

Tags: java, android

i get a jsonArray from server and show its data in an arraylist.
any jsonObject have a status field.
i want to check if status is "S" this jsonObject scroll to the top of the list.
for example 3 jsonobject status is "S",i want to scroll this three item to the top of the list and another jsonobject which have status "R" below this three item.

Comment: Which view you use listview or Recyclerview to show Your data

Comment: @sushantgosavi listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are usin a listview, try

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Or

```
list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

with 0 for the first item or another index of an item if you have it.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<notifList.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(notifList.get(i).getStatus().equals("S")) {
                            changeList.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

thats right??

Comment: Change `changeList.smoothScrollToPosition(count);` to `changeList.smoothScrollToPosition(i);` It will scroll multiple times based on the amount of items found.

Comment: if i=25 the item move to positon 25?!

Comment: Yes because the position will be 25, because you want to scroll to `S` and it is found on position 25 in your while loop. You can keep the `count` if you want to scroll to the **top** and not to the item

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using Recyclerview than use

```
layoutmanager.scrollToPosition(int position);
```

If you use Listview

```
listview.setSelection(int position);
```